# Iterating through the dictionary from json response

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax

My json view:

```
def validate_categories(request):
    obj = request.GET.get('categories', '')
    import json
    obj: list[int] = json.loads(obj)
    qs = Institution.objects.filter(categories__in=obj)

    return JsonResponse({institution.name: institution.id for institution in qs})
```

My Ajax:

```
  var catArrIdString = JSON.stringify(catArrIdInt)
  if (catArrId.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/ajax/validate_categories/",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        "categories": catArrIdString
      }
    }).done(function(institutionsByName) {
      for (const [key, value] in Object.entries(institutionsByName)){
        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
      }
    })
    .fail(function(e) {
      alert( "error" );
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
```

Then i have a dict like:
"Institution name": Institution Id

How can i iterate through it in javascript and use InnerHTML to put each of institution with its name and ID into a DIV?

Comment: Better to edit your question, than to write clarifications in the answer

Comment: I have done it.

Comment: Looks like your dictionary is simple array of values without specific keys. Can you show full `console.log(institutionsByName)`?

Comment: Then it lists all the dict: Object { "Schronisko dla bezdomnych": 2,  "Org. pozarządowa D": 7}

Comment: The only thing that i need is to know how to iterate through every position (value and key) in this ?function?

Comment: Oh, you almost do all right, just use `for ... of` instead `for ... in` and your example will work

Comment: It does! Thank you a lot :) You've solved my problem that i am struggling with much time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for iterate using usual loop

```js
const dictionary = {
"name1": 1,
"name2": 2,
"name3": 3,
};

document.body.innerHTML = Object.entries(dictionary)
  .map(([key,val]) => `<div>${key}: ${val}</div>`)
  .join('<br/>');
```

Comment: Please do not use only external links to answer a question. Explain what the user can do to solve the problem, and in case report some info from external websites by citing them

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I edit my answer, now it is better for you?

Comment: You reported some code, still I don't think you solved the OP problem. You reported some general code, but did not addressed the specific problem. Did you? Try to be more specific and answer the question

Comment: @RiccardoBucco The question is:
How can i iterate through dictionary in javascript and use InnerHTML to put each of institution with its name and ID into a DIV?

Look: iterate - check, javascript - check, innerHTML - check (i know few another ways for that), put each institutionwith its ID - check, DIV - check. Looks like i did addressed the specific problem full.

Usualy i dont write code for questions without examples of required html output, but specially for you i wrote little example